# How can I get conversationID when sending email outlook in c#

Tags: c#, outlook

I try to get ConversationID when I sending e-mail in c#.My mails send but ı can't get the conversationID.

```
try
   {
   Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
   Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
   mail.To = "abc@abc.com";
   mail.Subject = "This is subject";
   mail.Body = "This is body"; 
   mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
   mail.VotingOptions = "Agree;Disagree";
   ((Outlook.MailItem)mail).Send();
   MessageBox.Show("Message sent");
   MessageBox.Show(mail.ConversationID); 

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
    {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

When I run this code it gives me System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException.Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the message box statement above the `Send` method call:

```
try
   {
   Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
   Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
   mail.To = "abc@abc.com";
   mail.Subject = "This is subject";
   mail.Body = "This is body"; 
   mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
   mail.VotingOptions = "Agree;Disagree";

   MessageBox.Show(mail.ConversationID); 

   ((Outlook.MailItem)mail).Send();

   MessageBox.Show("Message sent");


   }
   catch (Exception ex)
    {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Try to call `Save` before accessing the `ConversationID`.

Comment: it gives the result empty for now :/

Comment: how can I do it i'm too new for this problem :/ please help me

Comment: Just try to add `mail.Save();` before the property call.

Comment: mail.Save();
MessageBox.Show(mail.ConversationID); 
((Outlook.MailItem)mail).Send();
it still gives me null and gives the same error